# Automatically add parent model id in nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, nested, url-routing, helper

With nested resource routes in Rails 3, such as the following:

```
resources :magazines do
  resources :ads
end
```

helpers such as `magazine_ad_path` are defined, to which I have to pass both a magazine and the ad, which is inconvenient if I just have a reference to the ad:

```
magazine_ad_path(@ad.magazine, @ad)
```

Is there a nice way to set up an `ad_path` helper that takes the `@ad` and returns the appropriate address including the magazine ID? (This would also then allow the use of `link_to @ad`, `redirect_to @ad`, etc., which automatically call the `ad_path` helper corresponding to the model class.)

Answer (score 2):

Shallow Routing seems to be what you're looking for. You can implement shallow nesting as below :

```
resources :magazines do
  shallow do
    resources :ads
  end
end
```

**OR**

```
resources :magazines, :shallow => true do
  resources :ads
end
```

Only the index and the new actions are nested.

Using nested resources tends to generate long URLs, shallow nesting helps remove parts (that  contain the parent resource route as well) that aren't necessarily required for certain actions(since a parent resource can be derived from a persisted child record).

Comment: It's true that this works, but I'd like to have the magazine id in the URL regardless. (In my case, it's not actually the plain ID; I'm using friendly_id and the ad identifier isn't necessarily unique outside of the magazine context.)

Answer (score 0):

One possible but ugly solution is:

```
module RoutesHelper
  def ad_path(ad)
    magazine_ad_path(ad.magazine, ad)
  end

  def ad_url(ad)
    magazine_ad_url(ad.magazine, ad)
  end

  def edit_ad_path(ad)
    edit_magazine_ad_path(ad.magazine, ad)
  end

  def edit_ad_url(ad)
    edit_magazine_ad_url(ad.magazine, ad)
  end

  ...
end

[ActionView::Base, ActionController::Base].each do |m|
  m.module_eval { include RoutesHelper }
end
```

Unfortunately, this has the disadvantage that I have to define different helpers for `_path` and `_url` because `redirect_to` uses the `_url` helpers, I have to write the `edit_` helpers manually (and maybe I'm missing some; not sure on that), and it's just plain ugly.

Answer (score 0):

One solution i like to use in this case is to make the instance returning his own path, like this:

```
class Ad
  def path action=nil
    [action, magazine, self]
  end
end
```

Then in your view you can use this array as a polymorphic route:

```
link_to @ad.path
link_to @ad.path(:edit)
```

Of course it also work with redirect_to, etc

Comment: Nice approach. I just don't think the model is the best place to add the method, though. I'd rather put it in the helper, or even somewhere inside the lib folder.